# Need many to one relationship in Polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have 3 models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The requirement is to have a same image for multiple products. i.e many products have one image.

`p1, p2, p3 -> img1`

Is there any way to achieve this without an extra table. Please help it.

Comment: what's your trying for this case, some code? whats wrong?

Comment: which one you are referring to as "an extra table"?

Comment: Will one image belong to many users? Will one image belong to both users and products? I'm assuming no for both, but you should clarify that bit.

Comment: joncalhoun, no for both. i need only for products.

Comment: Hi Monk_Code, Now the fields of images table: imageable_type and imageable_id are storing "User/Product" and "User_id/Product_id". If i create an extra table, i can store imageable_type and imageable_id as the new table name and id. and in the new table fields are media_id and product_id. But i want to achieve this without a new table.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you were looking for, but it will do what you are asking and is probably the simplest solution.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :products

    def imageables
        return users + products
    end
end
```